# View doesn't show the same after applying a function in the Controller

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, laravel-5

Hi i was trying to implement a code  where i can filter member by their roles or names this is my fucntion in the controller

profilecontrolle.php:

```
  public function membrevis()
  {
      $filter = isset($_GET['filter']) ? $_GET['filter'] : null;
      $query = DB::table('users')
          ->join('user_role', 'users.id', '=', 'user_role.user_id')
          ->join('roles', 'user_role.role_id', '=', 'roles.id')
          ->where('users.valid','=',0)
          ->select('users.*','roles.description');
      if ($filter != null) {
          $query->where('users.name','like','%'.$filter.'%')
             ->orWhere('roles.description','like','%'.$filter.'%');
      }

      $users = $query->get();

      return view('membre2',['users'=> $users]); 
  }
```

My view is a blade extending of a layout has the following code:

```
@extends('layouts.edu')

 @section('content')
 <div class="container">     
     <div class="row">

         <form action="/profilecontroller/membrevis" method="get">
             <input type="text" name="filter" >
             <button type="submit">filter</button>
         </form>

         @foreach($users as $user) 
             <h4 class="media-heading">{{ $user->name }}</h4>
         @endforeach

     </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

The problem is ever since i launch my function membrevis()
 it changes the syle of my view even though i have this:

```
  return view('membre2',['users'=> $users]);
```

which means that teh view membre2 has the request and the result on it..

Can anyone tell me how i can change this command line to an otehr one that allows my blade to stay as it is even after launching the function? Thank you

*****************HTML CODE RETURNED*******************************

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
 <meta name="description" content="Creative - Bootstrap 3 Responsive Admin Template">
  <meta name="author" content="GeeksLabs">
   <meta name="keyword" content="Creative, Dashboard, Admin, Template, Theme, Bootstrap, Responsive, Retina, Minimal">
   <link rel="shortcut icon" href="img/favicon.png">

  <title>Cours DZ</title>

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
 <!-- bootstrap theme -->
 <link href="css/bootstrap-theme.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <!--external css-->
   <!-- font icon -->
   <link href="css/elegant-icons-style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link href="css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
 <!-- full calendar css-->
  <link href="assets/fullcalendar/fullcalendar/bootstrap-fullcalendar.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="assets/fullcalendar/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.css" rel="stylesheet" />
     <!-- easy pie chart-->
  <link href="assets/jquery-easy-pie-chart/jquery.easy-pie-chart.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />
  <!-- owl carousel -->
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/owl.carousel.css" type="text/css">
   <link href="css/jquery-jvectormap-1.2.2.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <!-- Custom styles -->
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/fullcalendar.css">
  <link href="css/widgets.css" rel="stylesheet">
 <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="css/style-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet" />
 <link href="css/xcharts.min.css" rel=" stylesheet">
  <link href="css/jquery-ui-1.10.4.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
 <meta name="description" content="Creative - Bootstrap 3 Responsive Admin Template">
   <meta name="author" content="GeeksLabs">
 <meta name="keyword" content="Creative, Dashboard, Admin, Template, Theme, Bootstrap, Responsive, Retina, Minimal">
 <link rel="shortcut icon" href="img/favicon.png">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

 <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <!-- bootstrap theme -->
  <link href="css/bootstrap-theme.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <!--external css-->
  <!-- font icon -->
  <link href="css/elegant-icons-style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
 <link href="css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <!-- Custom styles -->
  <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
 <link href="css/style-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet" />

  <!-- =======================================================
  Theme Name: NiceAdmin
Theme URL: https://bootstrapmade.com/nice-admin-bootstrap-admin-html-template/
 Author: BootstrapMade
  Author URL: https://bootstrapmade.com
```

======================================================= -->

```
 <body>
   <!-- container section start -->
  <section id="container" class="">


  <header class="header dark-bg">
  <div class="toggle-nav">
    <div class="icon-reorder tooltips" data-original-title="Toggle Navigation" data-placement="bottom"><i class="icon_menu"></i></div>
  </div>

  <!--logo start-->
  <a href="http://127.0.0.1:8001" class="logo">COURS <span class="lite">DZ</span></a>
  <!--logo end-->
   <div class="top-nav notification-row">
    <!-- notificatoin dropdown start-->
    <ul class="nav pull-right top-menu">

      <!-- task notificatoin start -->
    <li> <div class="nav search-row" id="top_menu">
    <!--  search form start -->
    <ul class="nav top-menu">



    <a href="http://127.0.0.1:8001/login"> <button type="button" class="btn dark-bg"><font size = "3" face = "Times new roman" color = "white">CONNEXION </font></button></a>

  <!--logo end-->
      <li>
        <form class="navbar-form">
          <input class="form-control" placeholder="Rechercher" type="text">
        </form>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <!--  search form end -->
  </div>
         </li> 

        </ul>
      </li>


      </li>

     </ul></div>
       </header>
   <!--header end-->

   <!--sidebar start-->
   <aside>
  <div id="sidebar" class="nav-collapse ">
    <!-- sidebar menu start-->
    <ul class="sidebar-menu">
      <li class="active">
        <a class="" href="http://127.0.0.1:8001">
                      <i class="icon_house_alt"></i>
                      <span>Page d'acceuil</span>
                  </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="http://127.0.0.1:8001/cours">
                      <i class="icon_document_alt"></i>
                      <span>Cours</span>

                  </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="http://127.0.0.1:8001/evenement">
                      <i class="icon_table"></i>
                      <span>Evènements</span>

                  </a> </li>
      <li>
        <a href="http://127.0.0.1:8001/groupevis">
                      <i class="icon_group"></i>
                      <span>Groupes</span>
                  </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="http://127.0.0.1:8001/membre2">
                      <i class="icon_documents_alt"></i>
                      <span>Membres</span>

                  </a>

      </li>

      <li class="sub-menu">
        <a href="javascript:;" class="">
                      <i class="icon_piechart"></i>
                      <span>Statistiques</span>

                  </a>

    </ul>
    <!-- sidebar menu end-->
  </div>
   </aside>
   <!--sidebar end-->

   <!--main content start-->
   <section id="main-content">
  <section class="wrapper">
     <!--overview start-->
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-12">
        <h3 class="page-header"><i class="fa fa-laptop"></i> Page d'acceuil</h3>
        <ol class="breadcrumb">

          <li><i class="fa fa-home"></i><a href="http://127.0.0.1:8001">Cours DZ</a></li>
          <li><i class="fa fa-laptop"></i>Page d'acceuil</li>
        </ol>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div>   </div>  


   <div class="container">     
   <div class="row">

    <form action="/profilecontroller/membrevis" method="get">

     <input type="text" name="filter" >
                   <button type="submit">filter</button>
                                  </form> <br><br>

    </div>
    </div>
     </div>
      </section>
    <!--main content end-->
     </section>
     <!-- container section start -->

    <!-- javascripts -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <script src="http://127.0.0.1:8001/js/like.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">

   var url = "http://127.0.0.1:8001/like";
  var url_dis = "http://127.0.0.1:8001/dislike";
  var token = "7HRazckkC7aUoYpcRZKhN2xuC0UqX8QQxS6Ibn6X";
    </script>

  <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
 <script src="js/jquery-ui-1.10.4.min.js"></script>
 <script src="js/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.min.js"> 
   </script>
    <!-- bootstrap -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
   <!-- nice scroll -->
  <script src="js/jquery.scrollTo.min.js"></script>
   <script src="js/jquery.nicescroll.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
   <!-- charts scripts -->
  <script src="assets/jquery-knob/js/jquery.knob.js"></script>
  <script src="js/jquery.sparkline.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="assets/jquery-easy-pie-chart/jquery.easy-pie-chart.js"> 
  </script>
 <script src="js/owl.carousel.js"></script>
 <!-- jQuery full calendar -->
  <script src="js/fullcalendar.min.js"></script>
 <!-- Full Google Calendar - Calendar -->
 <script src="assets/fullcalendar/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.js"></script>
 <!--script for this page only-->
 <script src="js/calendar-custom.js"></script>
 <script src="js/jquery.rateit.min.js"></script>
 <!-- custom select -->
 <script src="js/jquery.customSelect.min.js"></script>
 <script src="assets/chart-master/Chart.js"></script>

  <!--custome script for all page-->
 <script src="js/scripts.js"></script>
  <!-- custom script for this page-->
   <script src="js/sparkline-chart.js"></script>
   <script src="js/easy-pie-chart.js"></script>
   <script src="js/jquery-jvectormap-1.2.2.min.js"></script>
   <script src="js/jquery-jvectormap-world-mill-en.js"></script>
   <script src="js/xcharts.min.js"></script>
   <script src="js/jquery.autosize.min.js"></script>
   <script src="js/jquery.placeholder.min.js"></script>
   <script src="js/gdp-data.js"></script>
  <script src="js/morris.min.js"></script>
   <script src="js/sparklines.js"></script>
   <script src="js/charts.js"></script>
   <script src="js/jquery.slimscroll.min.js"></script>
   <script>
  //knob
  $(function() {
    $(".knob").knob({
      'draw': function() {
        $(this.i).val(this.cv + '%')
      }
    })
  });

  //carousel
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#owl-slider").owlCarousel({
      navigation: true,
      slideSpeed: 300,
      paginationSpeed: 400,
      singleItem: true

    });
  });

  //custom select box

  $(function() {
    $('select.styled').customSelect();
  });

  /* ---------- Map ---------- */
  $(function() {
    $('#map').vectorMap({
      map: 'world_mill_en',
      series: {
        regions: [{
          values: gdpData,
          scale: ['#000', '#000'],
          normalizeFunction: 'polynomial'
        }]
      },
      backgroundColor: '#eef3f7',
      onLabelShow: function(e, el, code) {
        el.html(el.html() + ' (GDP - ' + gdpData[code] + ')');
      }
    });
  });
   </script>

     </body>

   </html>
```

Comment: can you be more specific what do you mean style is changing¿ Which style? PHP has nothing to do with style(css)?

Comment: @GaimZz that's the point!! it has nothing to do with it but profilecontroller.php tend to show me a view (membre2.blade.php) that's quiet far from the real view it's like the view doesnt extend from any layout no css nothing, any ideas please?

Comment: Can you show the html code which is returning? so we can help you, if you go to the view normaly without the function you are sure it looks as expected? Class media-heading is meant to be placed inside a media, so you could try to remove it but I don't think it's because of that. For more readability you can try to return the view like this: `return view('membre2', compact('users'));`

Comment: Hi @GaimZz I just updated my post with the HTML returning there where you can  see its extending from a layout but it doesnt show all the css and js and i know the problem is with the controller returning the data to my view, any help??

Answer (score 0):

The problem is probably on your layout file, where you are closing 1 div more than necessary, that might be the reason you see your html messed up, so try removing that one closing tag from your layout file that's disrupting your html:

```
</div> // close row
</div> // close container
 </div> // this is closing nothing therefore it should be removed from layout file 
  </section>
```

On your layout.edu file check after you are yielding the 'content' section, you will probably find 1 closing div tag after that, you need to remove it

Comment: Hi, thank yo for your comment, i removed it but its still the same thing, don't you think it has to do with js files?

Comment: Bro, you should know that the problem isn't your controller, it's just in your view I don't know about all of your scripts or what do they do so I can't help you with that